# Remove json from another json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two JSON, with different structure and I need to remove one of them from the other.

for example:

users JSON:

```
{
   0: { id: 'user134', avatar: 'user222.gif' },
   1: { id: 'user043', avatar: 'user242.gif' },
   2: { id: 'user093', avatar: 'user357.gif' },
   3: { id: 'user193', avatar: 'user543.gif' }
}
```

admin JSON:

```
{
   id: 'user093',
   avatar: 'user357.gif'
}
```

after deleting admin from users list, the result should be like this:

```
{
   0: { id: 'user134', avatar: 'user222.gif' },
   1: { id: 'user043', avatar: 'user242.gif' },
   3: { id: 'user193', avatar: 'user543.gif' }
}
```

I tried to use `_.pullAllBy(array, values, [iteratee=_.identity])` but it's not work with me!

Comment: This is not valid JSON.

Comment: Can you make the first object an array ? since keys are just index numbers, then it makes everything simpler

Comment: JSON has absolutely nothing to do with your question.

Comment: First of all, as others said, this is not a valid JSON. Also, I think this not a proper way to define an array of objects!

Comment: @SajadJafari Better yet, a Set, but Vue.js has no support for these structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

[`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

> The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

[`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> The forEach() method executes a provided function once for each array element.

[delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

> The JavaScript delete operator removes a property from an object; if no more references to the same property are held, it is eventually released automatically.

[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

> The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

```js
var obj = {
   0: { id: 'user134', avatar: 'user222.gif' },
   1: { id: 'user043', avatar: 'user242.gif' },
   2: { id: 'user093', avatar: 'user357.gif' },
   3: { id: 'user193', avatar: 'user543.gif' }
}


var obj2 = {
   id: 'user093',
   avatar: 'user357.gif'
}
Object.values(obj).forEach(function(o,i){
  if(JSON.stringify(obj2) == JSON.stringify(o))
    delete obj[i];
});
console.log(obj);
```

**OR:** If you want to check by individual key

```js
var obj = {
   0: { id: 'user134', avatar: 'user222.gif' },
   1: { id: 'user043', avatar: 'user242.gif' },
   2: { id: 'user093', avatar: 'user357.gif' },
   3: { id: 'user193', avatar: 'user543.gif' }
}


var obj2 = {
   id: 'user093',
   avatar: 'user357.gif'
}
Object.values(obj).forEach(function(o,i){
  if(obj2.id == o.id && obj2.avatar == o.avatar)
    delete obj[i];
});
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
let user = {
   0: { id: 'user134', avatar: 'user222.gif' },
   1: { id: 'user043', avatar: 'user242.gif' },
   2: { id: 'user093', avatar: 'user357.gif' },
   3: { id: 'user193', avatar: 'user543.gif' }
};

let admin = {
   id: 'user093',
   avatar: 'user357.gif'
};
for(key in user){
    if(user[key].id  === admin.id){
        delete user[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean [object literal, and not JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Object_literal_notation_vs_JSON). You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve this:

```js
const data = {
   0: { id: 'user134', avatar: 'user222.gif' },
   1: { id: 'user043', avatar: 'user242.gif' },
   2: { id: 'user093', avatar: 'user357.gif' },
   3: { id: 'user193', avatar: 'user543.gif' }
};

const admin = {
   id: 'user093',
   avatar: 'user357.gif'
};

const result = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, currentKey) => {
  if (data[currentKey].id !== admin.id) acc[currentKey] = data[currentKey];

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not a JSON, it's just a JavaScript Object.

İf you want to delete an object inside another object by its id field, you can use `for ... in` method like this.

```
 var o = {
     0: { id: 'user134', avatar: 'user222.gif' },
     1: { id: 'user043', avatar: 'user242.gif' },
     2: { id: 'user093', avatar: 'user357.gif' },
     3: { id: 'user193', avatar: 'user543.gif' }
  }

  for (var baseKey in o) {
    if (o[baseKey].id == "user093") {
      delete o[baseKey];
      console.log(o);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let user = {
    { id: 'user134', avatar: 'user222.gif' },
    { id: 'user043', avatar: 'user242.gif' },
    { id: 'user093', avatar: 'user357.gif' },
    { id: 'user193', avatar: 'user543.gif' }
};
let admin = {
    id: 'user093',
    avatar: 'user357.gif'
 };
let new_user=user.map(u=>{
    if(u.id!=admin.id){
        return u;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let mainObject ={
   0: { id: 'user134', avatar: 'user222.gif' },
   1: { id: 'user043', avatar: 'user242.gif' },
   2: { id: 'user093', avatar: 'user357.gif' },
   3: { id: 'user193', avatar: 'user543.gif' }
}

let filterObject = {
   id: 'user093',
   avatar: 'user357.gif'
}

Object.values(mainObject).forEach(({id, avatar},index)=> { 
  if(id === filterObject.id) delete mainObject[index];
})
console.log(mainObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what you are showing are just javascript objects, not JSON.  But presuming that's what you mean  you can do this:

```
let users = {
   1: { id: 'user043', avatar: 'user242.gif' },
   2: { id: 'user093', avatar: 'user357.gif' },
   3: { id: 'user193', avatar: 'user543.gif' } 
};

delete users['2'];
```

users will now include the objects at keys 1 and 3.

Comment: Dude! What is this? What happened to the `admin` object? You just decided to delete `user["2"]` ??